# Google Apps Script / interrupt a loop to the next counter if a condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to continue to the next loop counter if a condition is met (example value of a cell "Q+counter"= 2)

This is the start of my function

(The axie == "null" stops the script.)

```html
function scraperOwner(){

  var sh3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Axies Tracker");
  var positionSheet = sh3.getRange('N8').getValue();
  for (var counter = positionSheet; counter < Infinity; counter = counter + 1) {

  var axie = sh3.getRange('P'+counter).getValue();

  if(
    axie == "null"
     ){
       Logger.log("Nothing to do ")
    break;
  }

  var skipCondition = sh3.getRange('N'+counter).getValue();

< I need to insert here the condition if N+counter=2 then restart the loop >

... The script then continues the loop
```

Thanks ^^

Comment: Look at "continue;"

Comment: Thanks! it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop), if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop.

```
function scraperOwner(){

  var sh3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Axies Tracker");
  var positionSheet = sh3.getRange('N8').getValue();
  for (var counter = positionSheet; counter < Infinity; counter = counter + 1) {

  var axie = sh3.getRange('P'+counter).getValue();

  if(
    axie == "null"
     ){
       Logger.log("Nothing to do ")
    continue;
  }

  var skipCondition = sh3.getRange('N'+counter).getValue();
```